How I can ensure that any child of my Base Model in Eloquent will have same attributes no matter what?
I am making a base Class as a form of a "model template":

abstract class BaseModel
{
      use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'fullname',
        'user_id',
        'created_at',
        'slug'
    ];

    protected $appends = ['file_url'];

    abstract public function getFileUrlAttribute();
}


And I want to ensure that each child of my class BaseModel have path and slug attributes. Is there a way to enforce this?
